# Is there a function to print string as is in escaped mode?

Tags: c, linux, string

That is, `prt("a \t\n")` should print `"a \t\n"` literally,

is there any available function that does this?

Comment: No function can print the string "as it is" in the sense you're describing, because the string isn't actually like that: it doesn't contain a backslash or a `t` or an `n` to begin with. The translation is done by the compiler. However, a function can certainly replace a tab character with a backslash followed by a `t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you want to escape special characters; that is, you want to print `\n` instead of a newline character.

Not in the standard library, as far as I know. You can easily write it yourself; the core of the function is something like this:

```
static char *escape_char(char *buf, const char *s) {
    switch (*s) {
        case '\n': return "\\n";
        case '\t': return "\\t";
        case '\'': return "\\\'";
        case '\"': return "\\\"";
        case '\\': return "\\\\";
        /* ... some more ... */
        default:
            buf[0] = *s;
            buf[1] = '\0';
            return buf;
    }
}

/* Warning: no safety checks -- buf MUST be long enough */
char *escape_string(char *buf, const char *s)
{
    char buf2[2];
    buf[0] = '\0';
    for (; *s != '\0'; s++) {
        strcat(buf, escape_char(buf2, s));
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Generating the function body is also an option, as it can get quite tedious and repetitive.

This is how you can test it:

```
int main()
{
    const char *orig = "Hello,\t\"baby\"\nIt\'s me.";
    char escaped[100];
    puts(orig);
    puts(escape_string(escaped, orig));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reading the other answers, I realize I may have interpreted the question in a different way.

Comment: No, you interpreted it right, all the others interpreted it wrong. :) Your answer is not very correct though. There's no backslashes returned.

Comment: Corrected and tested. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Glib has a function [g_strescape()](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strescape) which does this. If the added dependency to glib is not a problem for you, at least.

Answer (score 4):

No, because string literals are already "unescaped" during the parsing of the source code, so the compiler never sees the literal backslashes or quotation marks. You'll just have to escape the backslashes yourself: `"\"a \\t\\n\""`.

Alternatively you could take a given string and search and replace all occurrences of control characters by their escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslashes and the quotes with backslashes:

```
printf( "\"a \\t\\n\"" );
```

Comment: No, the point is that one don't need to rewrite the parameters, it should be done inside the function.

Comment: As Kerrek noted, you could do a write a function that does that, but you'd still have trouble with the quotes, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a function as such but you can always

```
printf("a \\t\\n");
```